Are All The Notes Not Part Of A Chord Non Chord Tones?

I ask because the main melody is in A chord, but it contains a lot of non chord tones. For example, I can say the F# is an escape tone since it is approached by step from E and left by skip to A. But there are a lot of non chord tones. So the G is a non chord tone. It's approached by skip and then stays there and then steps down to another non chord tone. Is it an anticipation and then a suspension?
Or is all this unnecessary since these are part of the D maj scale.
When do you actually say a note is a non chord tone then?

There is no chord for the first three measures and arguably the fourth, and arguably there's no basis to assert that the passage from measure 5 to the first half of 8 is A because it contains no C sharps.  Why would you say the chord is A at any point before the middle of measure 8?

All tones not part of the prevailing chord (i.e., harmony) are, by definition, non-chord tones. The problem here, IMO, stems from an incomplete analysis.
Consider the first four measures. These could be very easily interpreted (heard) as D   | A7 D | A(7)  | A(7)  |. Looked at that way, the open fifth in the left hand in mm. 5 – 8 contains the common-tone A plus the sometimes-non-chord pedal-tone E.
Now m. 5's downbeat E is an accented lower neighbor and the measure's final G is an anticipation of a chord tone. The following F# is a passing tone and the only non-chord tone in the right hand. Measures 7 and 8 are entirely chord tones.



Are All The Notes Not Part Of A Chord Non Chord Tones?

Yes. By definition that is what non-chord tones are.
But the chord tone/non-chord tone distinction relies, of course, on a clear identification of what the chords are. Sometime chord identification is obvious, but not always. Often chords are only partially voiced, or result from complex polyphonic texture, or are implied by a single melodic line. In those cases chord identification can be tricky.
I see two important things to consider with your music example.
First, if you want to play with the standard, common practice era sensibilities of harmony, you should deal with the importance of the bar line and harmonic expectations. A general concept is chords change at the bar line.
The implied harmony of the second to third measures is clear...

...in part from the pitches used, but reinforced by their placement relative to meter and the bar line. The A7 could alternately be considered an implied viio chord. One way or another the implied harmony is a dominant of some kind.
Now let's go to measure 1.

...For example, I can say the F# is an escape tone since it is approached by step from E and left by skip to A.

You need to do more that just say that. You need to give the implied harmonic analysis to go with that. And importantly, that analysis can't be contrived. It needs to be convincingly heard as analyzed.
You didn't explicitly say you think the implied chord for m. 1 is an A, but based on the later harmonization in m. 5 I assume that is your meaning.
The problem with that idea is moving from m. 1 to m. 2 we would then have harmony | A | A7... where there is no change in chord root when moving over the bar line. That runs contrary to general expectations and calls into question whether one chord on either side of the bar line is not a good harmonic choice.
My point relies on a general idea about harmony and the bar line, but many other factors could come into play. With nothing else to go on but your example, I'm saying m. 1 is harmonically unclear, and one factor contributing to that lack of clarity is no chord change at the bar line.
The second thing to consider is the special non-chord tone case of a pedal.
When you repeat the opening four measures and harmonize the whole thing with A and E in the bass, that bass sounds as a pedal. In m. 6 we see and hear the harmonic effect of that pedal...

...the pedal is the non-chord tone while treble part is giving the actual harmonic tones. (A technical note: the E in the pedal is a dissonant non-chord tone, but the A, while a chord tone of the implied D triad, is forming a dissonant interval of a perfect fourth relative to the D above.)
If the A and E in the bass were not held for four measures, or if the treble motion through D and F# were briefer, we could have a different harmonic analysis.

To go any further I think we need to know what your intentions are regarding musical form and how these phrases fit into a design. It isn't clear if your example is the open ten measures of a piece. With the pedal harmony you chose you might be intending a musette style piece where the pedal is on the tonic rather than dominant. Also, given the example, it isn't clear if you want clearly major key or perhaps mixolydian tonality.
Small tweaks melodically can potentially have big implications for harmony. If your initial escape tone motion were dropped just one step to D4 E4 A3 instead of E4 F#4 A, you could have a much clearer implied harmony of | D | A7 D | A |, and that works nicely with the bar line. You could state the melody without harmonization for an opening and then repeat it with various harmonic treatments. Maybe a pedal on tonic in musette fashion, maybe chord changes in the bass, maybe a dominant pedal at some point.
You could do lots of things. But your question about non-chord tones is really about the "surface detail" of the music and it will be subordinate to the larger structural design. In one sense your analysis of F# in m. 1 as an escape tone in an A chord is correct, but what if the more fundamental harmonic error is why the structure may not be best served by an A chord in m. 1 and m. 5? IMO, first get the chords in those measures right, then craft your melody using an escape tone figure accordingly.
